# time format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time

Does anyone know how can I format a select statement datetime value to only display time in SQL Server?

example:

```
Table cuatomer
id   name   datetime
1    Alvin  2010-10-15 15:12:54:00
2    Ken    2010-10-08 09:23:56:00
```

When I select the table I like the result will display as below

```
id   name    time
1    Alvin   3:12PM
2    Ken     9:23AM
```

Any way that I can do it in mssql?

Comment: For those searching for format examples, see this very http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx It helped my understanding of the conversion strategies greatly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a combination of CONVERT, RIGHT and TRIM to get the desired result:

```
SELECT ltrim(right(convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 100), 7))
```

The `100` you see in the function specifies the date format `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`, and from there we just grab the right characters.

You can see more about converting datetimes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: why trim when you can just access the time straight away.

Comment: @Pavan - I added the TRIM because there may be a leading space for times other than 10, 11 or 12 AM/PM.  I didn't like format 108 because it doesn't include AM/PM like @Jin Yong asked for.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the CONVERT function like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, your_datetime, 108)
```

However, this is 24-hour clock, no AM/PM.

Comment: Explanation of the 108, and alternative styles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Answer (score 6):

This will get the time from a datetime value and also give the am or pm add on

```
SELECT RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,getDate(),100),8)),7)
```

will always return the date in **HH:mmAM** format.

Note the lack of space

Or

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,getDate(),100),7)),7),'AM',' AM'),'PM',' PM')
```

will always return the date in **HH:mm AM** format.

Hope that helps.

**PK**

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)
+ ' ' + RIGHT(convert(varchar, getdate(), 100), 2) as Time
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use:

```
select

convert(varchar,getdate(),114)
```

You might be able to manually construct the query like:

```
string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO test (DateOnlyField, TimeOnlyField) VALUES ('{0}', '1899-12-30 {1}')", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(), TimeString)
```

I dunno if this might work to:

```
Create Table Schedule( ScheduleID Integer Identity, ScheduledTime DateTime )

Go

Insert Into Schedule( ScheduledTime ) Values( '10:15:00 AM' )

Go

Select ScheduledTime As DBScheduledTime, Convert( VarChar( 10 ), ScheduledTime, 114 ) As ScheduledTime

From Schedule

Go

Drop Table Schedule

Go
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  A few pointers, if I may.  (1) You may want to edit your post, highlight your code, and press the '101010' button, it will format the code nicely.  (2) I see some C# code in there?  It may be better if you provide straight SQL scripts.  (3) Your output isn't in AM/PM format.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using SQL Server 2008 or Higher You can use the following statement:

```
SELECT Convert( VarChar( 10 ), CAST([columnName] AS TIME(0)), 100 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MySql** 
you can use `TIME_FORMAT()`

**Code ↓↓**

```
SELECT name, time_format(datatime,'%H:%i') as tine from cuatomer
```