# how to trim Date portion from DateTime Field in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a field that shows the date and time but i want to show only the time and would like to trim all the Date portion.  Here is what i have:

```
Field1
Dec 30 1899 10:13AM
```

and i want to show only the time like this:

```
Field1
10:13AM
```

I would like to use an update function to accomplish this.  How can i do this

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Field1=Time...
```

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to update them? You could do that where you show it(f.e. C#: `dateTime.ToShortDateString()`) or via sql: `CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)`.

Comment: What's the data type for Field1?

Comment: Duplicate of [time format in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877907/time-format-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS time)
```

Nevermind, overlooked AM/PM requirements. Anyway, [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877907/time-format-in-sql-server/679449) the answer:

> ```
> SELECT ltrim(right(convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 100), 7))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use Update (not format in the select).

As long as Field1 is DatTime DataType is will have a date component.
Cannot remove the date with an update.

If you want a time only column then create a Time column e.g. Time1

[time (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)

Then

update mytable set Time1 = CAST(Field1 AS time)