# How Can I merge two DateTime parts (Hour, Minute, Second) in SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime

I have two datetime field in my Table like these:

```
Transaction_RequestDateTime
Transaction_ResponseDateTime
```

I assigned value to this field in this way : (in C# win form program)

```
Transaction_RequestDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:ff");
Transaction_ResponseDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:ff");
```

as u see in above code, I used `hh` in responsing time, instead of `HH`. so when I want to get Datediff in SQL, It wont give me right different value.

for example the values are like this :

```
Transaction_RequestDateTime = 2015-02-13 21:28:53.390
Transaction_ResponseDateTime = 2015-02-13 09:28:54.500
```

as you can see, the difference is just in Minutes, our Second.
so, my question is this:

How can I change `Transaction_ResponseDateTime` values, as the hour part be like `Transaction_ResponseDateTime` 's hour?

for example I want to update these 2 records like this :

```
Transaction_RequestDateTime = 2015-02-13 21:28:53.390
Transaction_ResponseDateTime = 2015-02-13 21:28:54.500 // 21 instead of 09
```

Thanks for any helping...

Comment: How would you know the difference between (for example) 09 meaning 9am and 09 meaning 9pm?

Comment: by Transaction_ResponseDateTime  value. As I said, the hour in both fields are same.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't entirely clear to me. I think Shell has now provided an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cast the date into varchar datatype then use left and right part.
Like this

```
Declare @Date1 DateTime
SET @Date1 = '2015-01-01 15:45:00'

Declare @Date2 DateTime
SET @Date2 = '2015-12-31 12:00:00'

Declare @Combined DateTime

SET @Combined = Cast(Left(@Date2, 11) + Right(@Date1, 7) As DateTime)
print @Combined
```

You can also add the time after your sql date like this

```
SET @Combined = Cast(Left(@Date2, 11) + ' 09:00:00' As DateTime)
print @Combined
```

**EDITED:**

If you want to get a part of the date object in SQL then you can use `DatePart` function to get particular part of date. for example Year, Month, Date, Hour, Minutes and Seconds.

```
DatePart(expression, dateobjct)
--------------------------------

Year       : yy or yyyy
Month      : mm or m
Day        : dd or d
Weekday    : dw
Hour       : hh
Minutes    : mi or n
Seconds    : ss or s
Milli.Sec. : ms
```

You can use this function like this.

```
print DatePart(yyyy, @Date1)    
--Output will be 2015

SET @Combined = Cast(Left(@Date2, 11) + ' ' + Cast(DatePart(hh, @Date1) As Varchar) + ':00:00' As DateTime)
Select @Combined
```

Comment: Good one. one alternate solution I would like to add http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877907/time-format-in-sql-server

Comment: when I convert @Combined value to string, I got this error : Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Dec 31 2015  9:00AM' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are dealing with strings or not, but IF those fields are stored in the table as datetime then simply calculating the difference in hours and adding that difference to the incorrect field will work, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int identity primary key, [Transaction_RequestDateTime] datetime, [Transaction_ResponseDateTime] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Transaction_RequestDateTime], [Transaction_ResponseDateTime])
VALUES
    ('2015-02-13 21:28:53', '2015-02-13 09:28:54')
;

update table1
set Transaction_ResponseDateTime =  
    dateadd(hour, 
          datepart(hour,Transaction_RequestDateTime) 
        - datepart(hour,Transaction_ResponseDateTime)
    , Transaction_ResponseDateTime)
```

---

```
datepart(hour,Transaction_RequestDateTime)  = 19
- datepart(hour,Transaction_ResponseDateTime) = 10

so:
dateadd(hour, (19 - 10) , Transaction_ResponseDateTime)
```