# How to convert yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss into just hh:mm am/pm?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss` into just `hh:mm am/pm` in SQL Server? 
I want to convert `20060214 10:03:00` to `10:03 am`.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you want to convert a `datetime` into `hh:mm am/pm` format or a `varchar`?

Comment: Looks like the date is not stored as a `datetime` datatype... If you can, please do that

Comment: @nafas: how is a java question related to a T-SQL question?

Comment: @TimSchmelter you are right, it was a mistake. thx for correction

Comment: @nafas: feel free to fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [time format in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877907/time-format-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ltrim(right(convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 100), 7))
```

Someone asked a similar question here:

[time format in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877907/time-format-in-sql-server)