# how to convert the 24 hr to 12 hr in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have column of 24 hr and i need to change it to 12 hr, Please help .

```
Start time
  174300
  035800
  023100
```

The result should be

```
 Start time
  05.43 PM
  03.58 AM
  02.31 AM
```

Comment: what is the datatype of start time?

Comment: the datatype is varchar(20)

Comment: Don't store time in varchar...

Comment: Is there any other way to convert the time?

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877907/time-format-in-sql-server

Comment: length of  `174300` is always same?

Comment: In my Table i don't have date time format ,i have only the time string .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `STUFF` function to convert string to `Time` format

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(ColumnName,3,0,':'),6,0,':') AS TIME),100)
```

Comment: You should never use varchar without specifing the length, in this case you can even use CHAR(7). Good answer however..

Comment: @t-clausen.dk  In Convert function by default varchar take 30 char length.

Comment: There is a link about it [HERE](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) by Aaron Bertrand

Comment: Just Read Remark from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176089.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the examples above - the following will work.
You need to split the data into hours/minutes and cast it to time format, than convert it to the relevant type:

```
declare @data int
set @data = 174300



select convert(VARCHAR(15),cast(cast(left(@data, 2 )as varchar(2)) + ':' + cast(substring(cast(@data as nvarchar(6)), 3,2 )as varchar(2) ) as time),100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store time as varchar, instead alter your table and change the column type to datetime.

```
SELECT right(convert(varchar(25), Start Time, 100), 7)
```

The `100` you see in the function specifies the date format mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM), and from there we just grab the right characters.

You can see more about converting datetimes [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)